# When running Nginx + PHP-FPM in two different containers, can that configuration ever work without sharing a code volume?

Tags: php, docker, nginx, amazon-ecs

I have the following docker-compose.yaml file for local development that works without issue:

- Nginx container just runs the webserver with an upstream pointing to php
- Php runs just php-fpm + my extensions
- I have an external docker-sync volume which contains my code base which is shared with both nginx + php.
- The entire contents of my application is purely PHP returning a bunch of json api data.  No static assets get served up.

```
version: '3.9'

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge

services:
  site:
    container_name: nginx
    depends_on: [php]
    image: my-nginx:latest
    networks: [backend]
    ports: ['8080:80', '8081:443']
    restart: always
    volumes: [code:/var/www/html:nocopy]
    working_dir: /var/www/html

  php:
    container_name: php
    image: my-php-fpm:latest
    networks: [backend]
    ports: ['9000:9000']
    volumes: [code:/var/www/html:nocopy]
    working_dir: /var/www/html

volumes:
  code:
    external: true
```

I'm playing around with ways to deploy this in my production infrastructure and am liking AWS ECS for it.  I can create a single task definition, that launches a single service with both containers defined (and both sharing a code volume that I add in during my build process) and the application works.

This solution seems odd to me because now the only way my application can scale out is by giving me a {php + nginx} container set each time.  My PHP needs are going to scale faster than my nginx ones, so this strikes me as a bit wasteful.

I've tried experimenting with the following setup:

- 1 ECS service for just nginx
- 1 different ECS service for just php
- Both are load balanced, but by virtue of using Fargate and them being on different services, I don't have a way to add a `volumesFrom` block on the nginx container that would give it access to my code (which I package on the PHP container during my build process).  There is no reference to the PHP docker container that I can make that allows this to happen.

My configuration "works" in that the load balanced Nginx service can now scale independent of the load balanced PHP service.  They're able to both talk to each other.  But Nginx not having my code means it can't help but return a 404 on anything that I want my php upstream to handle.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/html/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /health {
        access_log off;
        return 200 'PASS';
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app-upstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   "Connection" "";
    }
}
```

Is there any nginx configuration I can write that would make this setup (without nginx having access to my code) work?

It feels like my only options are either copying the same code onto both containers (which feels weird), combining them both into the same container (which violates the 1 service/1 container rule), or accepting that I can't scale them as independently as I would like (which is not the end of the world).

Comment: Super late to the party, but this can absolutely work as we are doing it in our application.  you need a service discovery network attached to your php task/container.  then you can proxy your nginx requests there and it will auto distribute internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen a setup where Nginx and PHP were running in separate ECS tasks that scaled independently. I've always seen it where they are both running in the same ECS task, with a shared folder.

I wouldn't worry too much about this being "wasteful". You're adding a tiny amount of CPU usage to each Fargate ECS task by adding Nginx to each task. I would focus more on the fact that you are keeping latency as low as possible by running them both in the same task, so Nginx can pass requests to PHP over `localhost`.

Comment: I definitely agree that it's proven more to be more of a hassle than anything else to keep those two separate.  The elegance that I get from being able to manage each service discretely is bringing about other headaches for me with nginx that I can avoid if they're all on the same box.  On the bright side, learned a ton about nginx and I am seeing evidence that my intended idea can work.

Gonna consider this answer correct and package these two together for now and probably revisit this later for science.

Answer (score 1):

It's not required to share the volume between those two containers, the PHP scripts are required only by the PHP container, for Nginx it's only required to have network access to the PHP container, so it can proxy the requests.

To run your application on AWS ECS, you need to pack Nginx + PHP in the same container, so the load balancer proxy the request to the container, Nginx accepts the connection and proxy it to PHP, and then return the response.

Using one container for Nginx to act as a proxy to multiple PHP containers it's not possible using Fargate, it would require running the containers on the same network and somehow making the Nginx container proxy and balancing the incoming connections. Besides that, when a new PHP container were deployed, it should be registered on Nginx to start receiving connections.

Comment: By removing my `try_files` calls in the conf, I was at least able to see that concept work in action, which validates your point that nginx doesn't need access to that code.

I disagree that nginx + php _must_ be packaged on the same container: I launch both in the same VPC subnets, nginx's upstream goes to an NLB whose target group registers all my php ECS tasks.  No need for anything other pointing the PHP ECS service to the NLB and letting it do all the work of registering targets. 

I will grant that keeping them separate has felt like more hassle than benefit.

Comment: An interesting approach using NLB, congrats on your effort. I suggested packing them all in the same container due to simplicity, as you I don't like to have more than 1 service per container, even that is a way to solve and not too bad if your application is simple/not big. On other hand, you can consider EKS using nginx as Ingress.

Comment: @Luke Hi, I'm trying to recreate the same configuration you have in mind too.  Removing the "try_files" directive works.  I have another problem though: every time I deploy the php-fpm service again, nginx is no longer able to connect to it.  It is as if it fails to resolve the ”discovery service” after the deployment and goes to 502. But if I do a "nginx reload" from the task then it will work again.  Is it possible that once nginx loses the connection it does not try to connect again?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same struggle for a long time till I have moved all my PHP Apps to NGINX Unit.

https://unit.nginx.org/howto/cakephp/

This is an example how easy it is to have a single container setup to handle static files (html, css, js) as well as all the php code. To learn more about Unit in Docker check this out. https://unit.nginx.org/howto/docker/

Let me know if you have any issues with the tutorials.

Comment: Interesting, I'll definitely check it out.